# WSO2 identity server

Tags: wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

Trying to understand the tenant setup for the WSO2 identity server. i am unable to find where the java classes defined in the tenant-mgt.xml (ex:CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager.java) are located under the WSO2 4.0.0. Appreciate any help from WSO2 team

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source files [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.0.0/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/4.0.3/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/tenant/).